# Adding social sharing links to website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a site and I'm trying to add social sharing links on the site.

I **do not** want to use the generic buttons provided by Twitter, Google, or Facebook. I have some icons I'd like to use but want to hook the sharing pop-ups and interaction into them.

I tried using Facebook's guide and while I get the pop-up to display, the users status never actually posts to the page. I have Facebook's scripts in there but it just isn't publishing to my test users account.

I'm currently using Twitter intent and its working fine, but can't seem to get any Twitter meta data to populate into the published Tweet.

#### Facebook Meta Data

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Example Research Inforgraphic" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Example Research Inforgraphic" />
<meta property="og:image" content="images/share-content.jpg" />
```

#### Facebook Custom JS (on click, do the facebook stuffs)

```
$('.icon-fb').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
    FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'http://pbj.me',
    }, function(response){});
  });
```

#### Twitter Meta Data (just grabbed from a site, haven't edited content)

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@paulund_">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@paulund_">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://www.paulund.co.uk/example-image.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Image Title">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Image Description">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.paulund.co.uk/example-image.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image:width" content="500">
<meta name="twitter:image:height" content="500">
```

#### Twitter Intent Code Snippet

```
<li><a class="ss-icon ss-social icon-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&via=example" data-via="IBMResearch" data-related="pbj" data-hashtags="clientX" title="Share on Twitter">twitter</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that all your tags are correct using the [Twitter Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator).

You may also need to [get your cards approved by Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting#whitelisting).